# Configure HDFS WebUI DataNode DNS to use external DNS not internal DNS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, webui

I am reasonably knowledgeable about Hadoop configure, however, one problem has stumped me for many years. The WebUI for the DataNodes always shows the internal DNS FQDN for the DataNodes. I would like it to show the external DNS so that external browsers can access the nodes from outside of the cluster.

I hope someone may know which configuration key and file I can make this change to. The image below shows the HDFS WebUI area I am referring to.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I added the Public IP address to the nodes into my **hosts** file. It seems like a hack, but it works for now...

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx internal.dns shortname